# nodejs express read file and return response asynchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I want to do something like this

```
 router.get('/getforecast/:stationShortCode', function(req,res){
 var stationShortCode = req.params.stationShortCode;

 var fs = require('fs');
 fs.readFile("data/wx.hourly.txt", "utf8", function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
     //do operation on data that generates say resultArray;
     return resultArray;
  });

 res.send(resultArray);

});
```

obviously, `res.send` is called synchronously, whereas the file reads async. Is there a clever solution to this? Am I forced to actually pass in `res`?

Comment: You can just move `res.send(resultArray);` into the callback.  If that sounds like it won't work, you should look into how scoping works in JavaScript.

Comment: @AaronDufour, what if the file reading code is in another function?

Comment: @Md.IkramulMurad That function that the file reading code is in would need to take a callback argument which it will call with the results of reading the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fs.readFile("data/wx.hourly.txt", "utf8", function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;

    var resultArray = //do operation on data that generates say resultArray;

    res.send(resultArray);
});
```

Your file is read. The callback you passed to the `readFile` function is called. Then you can generate the data, and then you can send the response. Look into how asynchronous callbacks work, because here your code is not executed from top to bottom like you think it is. And because anonymous functions "remember" all the variables from the scope around them, you can use res inside that callback.